# How to enter custom sizing percent for Resize text, apps and other items in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I set **135%** for **Resize text, apps and other items** in Windows 8 Pro for my Acer 32" 4k monitor.

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 Pro; I could not find the way to enter custome sizing percent.

I'm wondering where I can enter the custom percentage.

### Windows 10

[image]

### Windows 8

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after playing around with few setting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]